# How to send and get data to/from SSH Tunnel in java (jsch )?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am a begginer to SSH Tunnels and I am trying to find a way to implement an SSH tunnel between host and server and through this tunnel, I want to send and get datas. I have searched on the net and I have seen that " jsch " can help me to implement a tunnel. The problem is since there was not enough comments on http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ I could not understand how to do it. If one of you knows about how to do it, can you please explain me ? Or if you have a little piece of code, can you please put with some comments ?

Thank you very much all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to do it in java ?

You'd better create a dynamic tunnel with ssh/PuTTY and use it in java thus ignoring the SSH complexity in your java code...

A dynamic tunnel is no more no less than a SOCKS 5 proxy which can easily be dealt with [Java networking](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) and `Proxy` + `ProxySelector` objects

Comment: Actually the way you do might be much easier but I was asked to implement a  program that can connect to host and send/get datas from it. I have implemented TCP, UDP etc. and now I was trying to implement it. The implementation must be dynamic so when I change my connection type to SSH in my config file, I have to have a SSH Tunnel. Thats why I want it in a complicated way. And thanks for the post I will absouletly try it.

Comment: So why don't you pack an ssh impl with your app (eg PuTTY's "plink") to do it silently in the background? I mean launch an external app with `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("plink -D 4564 host")`